# Fetching MongoDB data in Flask using pyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I need help with fetching data from a MongoDB collection in a simple Flask webpage. I've been trying to figure out how to fetch it but it has been of no help. My JSON data is an array of documents with 3 nested fields and I have attached it with the question. I'm trying to fetch all the data of the JSON template at first but I've been unable to. Once I know, I'll fetch the individual array.

Here is my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client.Learning
todos = db.data


@app.route('/')
def lists():
    for x in todos.find():
        y = print(x)
    return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And this is my data structure for the MongoDB data:

[image]

Any help or hint will be really appreciated so I can know how to fetch the data. Do I have to use HTML? If so, how can I fetch the arrays within arrays with HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using Flask-PyMongo.

It works like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask.json import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Learning"
mongo = PyMongo(app)


@app.route("/")
def lists():
    print([i for x in mongo.db.data.find({})])
    return jsonify([i for i in mongo.db.data.find({})])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I did that but it displays a blank page instead of showing the data. That's what been an issue for me.

Comment: Tried that as well but this time I get an Internal Server Error with 'NameError: name 'i' is not defined'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  it is  "i for i in"

Comment: It works so far, thanks for your help really. But I got another error popping up. 

`File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Coding/1028 Project/Flask/app.py", line 13, in lists
    return jsonify({i for i in mongo.db.data.find({})})
  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Coding/1028 Project/Flask/app.py", line 13, in <setcomp>
    return jsonify({i for i in mongo.db.data.find({})})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

I assume I need to access the individual data as key? But how can I actually access the data for my JSON datastructure?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967981/unhashable-type-dict-with-test-json

Comment: Maybe changing to jsonify([i for i in mongo.db.data.find({})]) can help. But I think the problem has to do with a dict inside another dict.